# MR job transactional or non-transactional

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2, mapr

When we use MR job with HDFS input / output then MR job behave as transactional i.e. it gets executed successfully or in case of failure data written to HDFS gets rolled back, we do not get partial results say, 3 out of 10 lines are present in output.

But when we run same MR job over HBase it behave as non-transactional i.e. if I have to put 10 objects to HTable and I called `context.write(...)` 3 times and failed on 4th iteration then I can see 3 puts in HBase though MR job has failed.

Is there any way via which we can have transactional MR job over HBase ? i.e. either entire output is written to HBase or no-output is written to HBase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try hbase incremental load? It's not trunsactions by definition but something like that. You can create hfiles for hbase via mapreduce job with all new data and then load it in batch via hbase incremental load. At least you can can sure that your mapreduce job sucessfully finished and all your data are checked by hbase table scheme and ready to load.

Comment: Yes. I tried that approach to use HFileOutputFormat. I thought of a design in which with 1 MR job I create HFiles and with other MR I dump it to HBase. But, Currently 'm using MapR distribution 4 and It has not implemented method for incremental load.